# Strange source command when start Julia REPL

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia

I am a bit fresh to Julia (and stack overflow), so it might be a dummy question. I am using VS code in ubuntu 18.04.

Every time I start Julia REPL from VS code (Ctrl+shift+P, then "Julia: Start REPL"), the Julia REPL starts with a strange command "source /home/$user_name/bin/activate" and then an error (of course source is not defined in Julia) :

```
ERROR: UndefVarError: source not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ REPL[1]:1
```

This problem was shown a couple of weeks ago but it does not affect my code at least for now. I have tried to search the problem but haven't found any similar questions. Any hints on what's going on? Many thanks!

---

Edit:
I think I might have used Conda somewhere.
Do "which Julia", I got:

```
/home/$user_name/julia-1.7.2/bin//julia
```

There is no "/home/$user_name/.julia/config/startup.jl" file, all the directories under "/home/$user_name/.julia/" are as follow:

```
artifacts  compiled  dev           logs      prefs       scratchspaces
clones     conda     environments  packages  registries
```

Then I found a "startup.jl" file under "$JULIA_INSTALL_FOLDER\etc\julia\startup.jl", with following content (seems like not helping on my problem).

```
# This file should contain site-specific commands to be executed on Julia startup;
# Users may store their own personal commands in `~/.julia/config/startup.jl`.
```

Comment: Did you use Conda or something like that to install Julia? That looks like it's trying to do Python-type environment activation for some reason, and of course Julia's environments don't work like that. Could you do a `which julia` and paste that output, and also paste the contents of your `/home/$user_name/.julia/config/startup.jl` file?

Comment: Thx for your reply! I have edited the details in the problem description.

Comment: Do you have VSCode-Python extension installed? If so, it maybe [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/13262) causing the problem. In that case, try setting `"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": false` as [per the recommendation there](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/13262#issuecomment-669292112) and restarting VS Code.

Comment: Thank you a lot @SundarR! It was the Python extension.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by following @SundarR's suggestion.
The problem was caused by the VSCode-Python extension installed.

Please see the comment above for the details and thanks again!